Can struct member accept dynamic variable?
I have multiple struct.  My main response struct is called WsPayload and it has a member variable called Payload.  The Payload can either my Earthquake struct or the EventReport struct.
My question:  How can I define my WsPayload Payload member variable so, it can accept both of my struct?  is there a dynamic variable that I can use in Go to accomplish this.
I'm building a websocket that receive payload from a client (JSON format).  Then I broadcast that message to websocket clients (JSON format).  In the payload, there's a member of the struct called Etype which determine the type of payload.  It could be Event or Earthquake payload.
type WsPayload struct {
    Action   string              `json: "action"`
    Message  string              `json: "message"`
    Etype    string              `json: "etype"`
    Payload  EventReport         `json: "payload"`.  //<---
    Conn     WebSocketConnection `json: "-"`
}

type Earthquake struct {
    Body     string `json: "body"`
    Location string `json: "location"`
    Rate     int    `json: "rate_earthquake"`
    Date     string `json: "lat"`
    Time     string `json: "lng"`
}

type EventReport struct {
    Title string   `json: "title"`
    Body  string   `json: "body"`
    Date  string   `json: "date"`
    Time  string   `json: "time"`
    Type  string   `json: "type"`
    Id    string   `json: "id"`
    Photo []string `json: "photo"`
}

At the moment, I can only define one struct at a time inside my WsPayload.

thanks @CeriseLimón I updated my question with more info.  Please could you provide an example of how can I implement this.

If the application does not interpret the message in any way, then read the message and bytes and broadcast the message as bytes. There's no need to convert the bytes to Go types and back.

If the application interprets the WsPayload fields, but not the contents of the Payload field, then declare the field as
 Payload  json.RawMessage `json:"payload"`


If the application does inspect the contents of the Payload field, then declare the field as type any.
type WsPayload struct {
    Action  string `json:"action"`
    Message string `json:"message"`
    Etype   string `json:"etype"`
    Payload any    `json:"payload"`
}

A value of any type can be assigned to the field and marshaled:
v := WsPayload{
    Message: "msg",
    Etype:   "report",
    Payload: EventReport{Title: "title"},
}
b, err := json.Marshal(v)
if err != nil { /* handle error */ }
// b is {"action":"","message":"msg","etype":"report","payload":{"title":"title","body":"","date":"","time":"","type":"","id":"","photo":null}}

To unmarshal the JSON, use json.RawMessage for the variant field:
var v WsPayload
u := struct {
    *WsPayload
    Payload json.RawMessage `json:"payload"`
}{
    &v,
    nil,
}
if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &u); err != nil { 
    /* handle error */ 
}

Switch on the Etype field to unmarshal the variant part:
switch u.Etype {
case "report":
    var r EventReport
    if err := json.Unmarshal(u.Payload, &r); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    v.Payload = r
// handle other types here...
default:
    log.Fatalf("type %s not handled", u.Etype)
}

The output is variable v.
https://go.dev/play/p/bDAQnZFWDvw

I just found out, the any type I can pass that field straight from receiving payload out broadcast to my clients without touch that field.  Awesome.  Thanks mate for your help!
